# Select2js does not work with multiselect and data array

Tags: jquery

I have spent hours trying to make this work but it does!
I am only able to select the first item; but not the 2nd item or more. Here is my code.

$(document).ready(function() {
    function format(item) { return item.FullName; }

```
$("#myTest1").select2({
    data: {
        results: [
            { MemberId: 1, FullName: "User1 Last" },
            { MemberId: 2, FullName: "User2 Last" },
            { MemberId: 3, FullName: "User3 Last" },
            { MemberId: 4, FullName: "User4 Last" }
        ], text: 'FullName'
    },
    id: function (obj) { return '#myTest1'; },
    formatSelection: format,
    maximumSelectionSize: 3,
    initSelection: function (element, callback) {
        console.log("init selection", element);
        var data = [];
        $(element.val().split(",")).each(function () {
            data.push({id: this, text: this});
        });
        callback(data);
    },
    //minimumInputLength: 1,
    multiple: true,
    formatResult: format
});
```

});

Here is the fiddlejs link http://jsfiddle.net/cphelefu/nngqgstz/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The id function expects to retrieve the id of the selected object, not the id of the select2. In other words, the function should be changed from

```
id: function (obj) { return '#myTest1'; },
```

to

```
id: function (obj) { return obj.MemberId; },
```

Updated Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/nngqgstz/3/

Comment: Thanks bud. Really appreciate it.